# TinyMCE : Remove Javascript from head

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am allowing Full Page Editing which has  and  tags as well . I added  as an invalidelement and it gets removed if I add  inside the body but it doesnt get removed if I have  inside the head element. Is there any way to handle that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to understand your question very clearly.
Though, I assume this might be the problem you are facing.

You are setting the "invalid_elements" while initializing in tinymce.

Possible reasons :

When you add it under the head section, it is certain that the script is defined before it is used. Also code in the head tag will be executed before that in the body(order of page loading).

When using JavaScript in a frames you must place all the JavaScript with the HEAD elements otherwise you cannot guarantee that the frames will be displayed correctly. TinyMce uses iframes to simulate whatever you type into rich text. So there might be a conflict due to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet to be used for that particular use case:

```
    switchStyle: function(url,tiny_id,url_to_replace){
        ed = tinymce.get(tiny_id);

        doc = $(ed.getBody().ownerDocument);

        // get stylesheet info alternative
        sheets = ed.getParam('content_css_alt');
        sheets_urls = [];

        if (url_to_replace){
            sheets_urls.push(url_to_replace);
        }
        else{
            sheets_urls.push(ed.getParam('content_css'));
            if (typeof sheets == "string"){
                sheets_urls.push(sheets);

            }
            else {
                for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
                    sheets_urls.push(sheets[i].url);
                }
            }
        }

        // remove all stylesheets from sheets_urls
        doc.find('link').each(function() {

            if (tinymce.inArray(sheets_urls, $(this).attr('href').split('?')[0]) !== -1) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });

        // set stylesheet
        doc.find('head:first').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + url + '"');

    },
```